# Split dictionary of lists into single lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, split

How can I split a dictionary of two lists into two different lists?

The structure of the dictionary is following:

```
{'key1': ['PTRG0097',
         'CPOG0893',
         'MMUG0444',
         'BTAG0783'],
'key2': ['CPOG0893',
         'MMUG0444',
         'PPYG0539',
         'BTAG0083']}
```

Comment: Could you show the structure of your dicts?

Comment: And what do you mean by splitting? What's the intended result?

Comment: The intended result is to have two different lists made from the two lists the dictionary contains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how we unroll:

```
>>> d = {'key1': ['PTRG0097', 'CPOG0893', 'MMUG0444', 'BTAG0783'], 'key2': ['CPOG0893', 'MMUG0444', 'PPYG0539', 'BTAG0083']}
>>> l1, l2 = d.values() # or this: d['key1'], d['key2']
>>> l1
['PTRG0097', 'CPOG0893', 'MMUG0444', 'BTAG0783']
>>> l2
['CPOG0893', 'MMUG0444', 'PPYG0539', 'BTAG0083']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
key1,key2 = yourdict.values()
```

should do it.

key1 and key2 now being lists containing the values in the corresponding dictionary list.

Answer (score 2):

How about `a['key1']` and `a['key2']`

or

`a.values()[0]` and `a.values()[1]`?

Answer (score -1):

Well you cna try something like :

```
l1=l2=[]
for key, val in dict.items()
    l1.append(key)
    l2.append(val)
```

as Each dict entry has key and val you can use items() method of dict

or 
      `l = [ for val in d.values() ]`

Regards

Comment: I find the downvote unfair since the question was vague and could well have been interpreted this way. +1 from me.

Comment: I wasn't the downvote, but due to typos neither of the code units are executable, and since l1 is l2, the first one doesn't produce what one might think it does (or, I think, what the author thinks it does.)