# From dictionary of lists to two lists of same length

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Consider the following dict:

```
{'key1': ['PTRG0097',
         'CPOG0893',
         'MMUG0444',
         'BTAG0783'],
'key2': ['CPOG0893',
         'MMUG0444',
         'PPYG0539',
         'BTAG0083']}
```

I would like to convert it to two lists or tuples:

```
keys   = ['key1', 'key1', 'key1', 'key1', 'key2', 'key2', 'key2', 'key2']
values = ['PTRG0097', 'CPOG0893', 'MMUG0444', 'BTAG0783', 'CPOG0893', 'MMUG0444', 'PPYG0539', 'BTAG0083']
```

There is probably an easy way to do this without looping in Python 3, but some of the solutions I found (e.g. [Split dictionary of lists into single lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828768/split-dictionary-of-lists-into-single-lists)) don't quite expand the dict this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how one would do it without explicit looping and assuming Python3.

```
>> list(zip(*[(k, v) for k, vs in d.items() for v in vs]))
[('key2', 'key2', 'key2', 'key2', 'key1', 'key1', 'key1', 'key1'),
 ('CPOG0893',
  'MMUG0444',
  'PPYG0539',
  'BTAG0083',
  'PTRG0097',
  'CPOG0893',
  'MMUG0444',
  'BTAG0783')]
```

The initial call to `list` is merely needed to print the iterator out. You don't need it if you want to save the values in variables:

```
[keys, values] = zip(*[(k, v) for k, vs in d.items() for v in vs])
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible without looping, but you can do it without an *explicit* loop:

```
from itertools import *

d = {'key1': ['PTRG0097',
              'CPOG0893',
              'MMUG0444',
              'BTAG0783'],
     'key2': ['CPOG0893',
              'MMUG0444',
              'PPYG0539',
              'BTAG0083']}

def expand(k, vs):
    return product([k], vs)

print(list(zip(*chain.from_iterable(starmap(expand, d.items())))))
```

In practice, you would of course go with musically_ut's answer, and not with this unreadable nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

You could get a list of tuples of the keys and values this way:

```
key_values = [(k, v) for k, vs in a.items() for v in vs]
```

and then from the list get a list of the keys and the values if this is more valuable:

```
keys = [i[0] for i in key_values]
values = [i[1] for i in key_values]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
keys = ['key1' for x in d['key1']] + ['key2' for x in d['key2']]
values = d['key1'] + d['key2']
```

Although, I suppose there's might be a siimpler version of the 'keys' line that doesn't use list-comprehensions.